# Best practice to implement composition and aggregation

Tags: uml, implementation, aggregation, diagram, composition

What practice is considered the best one when i have to translate an aggregation/composition of an UML Diagram drawn in Design Phase in implementation phase?

Comment: It clearly depends on your constraints and the concrete model you want to implement. Without that info there is no answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, when aggregation or composition has been used in a UML class diagram, it just means an association and doesn't have any additional meaning. So, the simple advice is: just translate an aggregation/composition of a UML design model to an association and implement it with suitable reference properties in the implementation (model).

You may want to read my article [Really Understanding Association, Aggregation, and Composition](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/880451/Really-Understanding-Association-Aggregation-and-C).

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas noted, I dont think there are any clear generally aplicable best practices. There's just so many different situations and different contexts which strongly affect selected approach.

Aggregations and compositions are analytical constructs and should not appear in design or implementation models very often, if at all.

What can be said is, that many people struggle to understand the meaning/semantics of aggregation/composition. Usually they tend to over-identify aggregations and compositions. These are in fact rather rare relationships within SW system models. Not every 1:N relationship is an aggregation.